# nullable object must have a value even after "HasValue" check

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, nullable

I have this LINQ to SQL query:

```
int? ID = null;
var query = from t in db.things where (!ID.HasValue || t.ID == ID.Value) select t;
```

Now in regular LINQ this works fine as expected, however in LINQ to SQL is throws a  "nullable object must have a value" exception.

Does LINQ to SQL do some weird interpretation of my null check? And if so, how do I implement this functionality correctly?

Comment: Did you check if t.ID is null?

Comment: t.ID is an int so it can't be null - it's also the Primary Key in the DB

Comment: still `t` can be null. it looks like `ID` is an attribute of `t`

Comment: Because t comes from the database, it is never null. I have confirmed this using breakpoints also - the exception is definitely coming from the call to ID.Value

Comment: The change you definition of t.ID to int?.  It looks like the database can be null but not your class.

Comment: @jdweng The ID in the database can't be null since it's the primary key, which also acts as a NOT NULL constraint. I believe this causes the interpretation in LINQ-to-SQL to represent it as an int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after using the debugger, turns out that LINQ to SQL doesn't understand the null check and just renders out SQL like this:

```
SELECT [t0]
FROM [dbo].[things] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[ID] = @p0
```

So when it goes to resolve the value of `@p0` it tries to evaluate `ID.Value` with no regard for my null check.

I solved this issue by using `GetValueOrDefault()`:

```
int? ID = null;
var query = from t in db.things where (!ID.HasValue || t.ID == ID.GetValueOrDefault()) select t;
```

In this case it is able to understand the where clause since the variable will always evaluate to some kind of value.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it something like:

```
int? ID = null;
if(ID.HasValue)
{
   var query = from t in db.things where (t.ID == ID.Value) select t;
}
else //when ID is null
{
   var query = from t in db.things select t;
}
```

Or it could be done in one line:

```
var query = ID.HasValue ? from t in db.things where (t.ID == ID.Value)select t : from t in db.things select t;
```

Comment: That's not quite right. When ID is null it should select all rows (at least that's how it's written in the question).

Comment: It should be goes to `else { var query = from t in db.things select t}`

Comment: Yeah this is a pretty good solution, the actual query is a bit longer than the example in my question, so there could be a bit of code duplication. However this is definitely an option

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you're correct Linq to SQL has an issue with this. Based on the answer to this question: [Linq to Sql is null in Where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785658/linq-to-sql-is-null-in-where-clause) you want something like this instead.

```
int? ID = null;
var query = from t in db.things where (!ID.HasValue || (ID.HasValue && t.ID == ID.Value)) select t;
```

Comment: Thanks Ben, looked promising but I tried this and got the same error